# Injecting a non-spring object into a spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Relatively new to Spring framework, so not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

I have the following non-spring classes / interface.

```
package a.b.c;
    public interface Dictionary {
}

package a.b.c;
    public class EnglishDictionary implements Dictionary {
}

package a.b.c;
    public class FrenchDictionary implements Dictionary {
}
```

I want to inject these classes into a spring managed application. So I created a config class like this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"a.b.c")}
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    Dictionary englishDictionary() {
        return new EnglishDictionary();
    }

    @Bean
    Dictionary frenchDictionary() {
        return new FrenchDictionary();
    }
}
```

And use these dictionaries in a Spring component class like this

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    Dictionary englishDictionary;
}
```

However, the application refuses to start with an error message saying "*Field englishDictionary required a bean of type 'a.b.c.Dictionary' that could not be found. Consider defining a bean of type 'a.b.c.Dictionary' in your configuration*.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try and remove the ComponentScan annotation with the a.b.c package? I think this might override the Spring Boot default configuration so that your AppConfig class is now not recognized correctly anymore.

Comment: Is your config getting invoked?  add a breakpoint in your `englishDictionary` method and see if it's invoked.

Comment: Can you please send us your package structure. I'm asking because the only reason I see this failing is that your `AppConfig` class is not in the same package(or under the same package) as your `Main` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AppConfig` class is not getting picked up by the Spring context and this is why you're receiving this exception. Please verify that your `AppConfig` class is in the same (or under the same) package as your `Main` class.

In other words, if your `Main` class is in package `com.example.demo` but your `AppConfig` class is in `com.example.beans` your Spring application will fail to start.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the package structure and it worked

Comment: Glad to know, happy developing :)

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective the better solution would be to have @Component(from Spring) annotation written at the class level.

```
package a.b.c;
    @Component
    public class EnglishDictionary implements Dictionary {
}

package a.b.c;
    @Component
    public class FrenchDictionary implements Dictionary {
}
```

Comment: What if he doesn't want to take a dependency on sprint in the other project